# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 21: invalid start byte

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to get an article off http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/04/01/net-us-foxconn-idUSBRE83004E20120401

```
url="http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/10/19/us-yahoo-korea-idUSBRE89I0EY20121019"
source = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
```

but receive the error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 107: invalid start byte

I have tried to use soup.encode(['windows-1252','ascii','iso-8859']) but in the first place, the soup cannot even be created.

Does anyone have any tips to share?

The error traceback, if it helps:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
parseReuters()
File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\test.py", line 39, in parseReuters
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
self._feed()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 185, in _feed
self.builder.feed(self.markup)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_lxml.py", line 195, in feed
self.parser.close()
File "parser.pxi", line 1209, in lxml.etree._FeedParser.close (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:90597)
File "parsertarget.pxi", line 142, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:99984)
File "parsertarget.pxi", line 130, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:99807)
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 294, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:9383)
File "saxparser.pxi", line 259, in lxml.etree._handleSaxData (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:95945)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Interesting, when I download that URL, the character at position 107 is a space (0x20). I don't see anything wrong with the data either (verified using `iconv`). Are you possibly hitting any proxy that manipulates the data or redirects you to another page?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if there's any proxy. Could you let me know how? Using chardet (which detects encoding), I found that the encoding was ascii. I had used BeautifulSoup on another site (esciencenews) and it worked fine.

Comment: At which statement do you get the error? Did you try printing `source` before passing it to beautiful soup?

Comment: The error occurs at soup = BeautifulSoup(source). I have also saved the web page's source code but the same error occurs (at a different position UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 40: invalid start byte)

Comment: I don't seem to be getting an error at all. Do you happen to have `lxml` installed?

Comment: Yes. This has happened on two separate computers in separate locations for reuters' articles. Haidro did you use the same code to check?

Comment: Yup, I did. Does doing `BeautifulSoup(source, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)` fix it?

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'HTML_ENTITIES'  (I'm using BS4)

Comment: Oops, that's for BeautifulSoup 3. Ignore that

Comment: UTF8 works for me. `source.headers.headers => charset=UTF-8` `s.decode('utf8')` also works but strange is `source.headers.getencoding() => '7bit'`

Comment: I have seen an error like this before when the encoding of the document did not match the encoding of the reader.  This happened when using UTF-16.