# BeautifulSoup utf-8 decoding error

Tags: python, utf-8, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract movie information from a website using BeautifulSoup 4. The relevant part of the code is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests

url = r'http://www.the-numbers.com/movies/1997/ASGOD.php' #is passed relevant url
r = requests.get(url)
soup = Soup(r.content, from_encoding = r.encoding)
```

Although it's working fine in a bunch of the website's pages just like it, on this particular one it returns the error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

At least that's usually the error. It also occasionally (and seemingly randomly) gives me a slightly different area, complaining about a different decode bit in a different position (eg 0xea in position 229).

The problem page is [here](http://www.the-numbers.com/movies/1997/ASGOD.php). An example of one that looks very similar but DOES work is [here](http://www.the-numbers.com/movies/1997/SCRM2.php).

I assume that there is some kind of encoding error on that page that throws BeautifulSoup for a loop, so I guess my question is whether there's some way to fix that error?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: Related (same error): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018977/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x80-in-position-21-invalid

Comment: It works just fine for me. Alternatively, use `Soup(r.text)` and leave the decoding to Unicode up to `requests`.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, it does the same thing for me either way. Also using urllib2 instead of requests. That's weird that it works for you, because it sounds like the question tehsockz linked to didn't replicate for everyone either. I'm using Python 2.7.3, Beautiful Soup 4.1.3 and requests 1.2.3, are you using something different? Will try on my other computer when I get off home. Could it be something to do with how requests (and urllib2) opens websites?

Comment: Hmm it works fine on my computer at home. Any ideas why it's inconsistent like that? Is it something about my internet connection at work? I think all libraries and python versions are the same.